# Postman test - error parsing JSON request with variables

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

My request body looks like this
[image]

"pulic_token" variable is ready defined.

My pre-request test looks like this:

```js
pm.test("Public token is correct", () => {
    const req = JSON.parse(request.data);
    pm.expect(req.public_token).to.be.a("string");
});
```

The error:

```
JSONError: Unexpected token 'p' at 4:21 "public_token": {{public_token}} ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Every “string” must be quoted with double quote `”`

Comment: Why does postman assume that my "public_token" is a string? Type confusion is a possible mistake and I'm trying to test that

Comment: It has nothing to do with postman, it’s a JSON specification https://www.json.org/json-en.html only numbers, object and arrays can be without quotes

Answer (score 0):

The error is from

```
JSON.parse(request.data)
```

The error says :

```
JSONError: Unexpected token 'p' at 4:21 "public_token": {{public_token}} ^
```

THis indicate that public_token variable was not resolved , if it was resolved the error would be something like (assuming value of variable is pet)

```
JSONError: Unexpected token 'p' at 4:21 "public_token": pet ^
```

So check whether correct environment or variable is defined

**Output:**

1. when environment not selected
2. when environment was selected

[image]